# Date of introduction of TO-92 transistors

Tags: transistors, repair, history

I'm trying to date a circuit from an organ. It contains transistors in a TO-92 (plastic) package.

Approximately when did these transistors first appear?

[image]

Comment: I personally remember plastic TO-92 transistors from the late 1960s, but I'm sure they originated much earlier than that.  This is not a useful way to date your board.

Comment: Are there any ICs on there with date codes? For example 7520 (20th week of 1975) or similar. Or check the board carefully for e.g. a date etched in the copper.

Comment: I don't have access to the organ just now, as it is a friends' - that is the only photo he gave. I will take a look in the next couple of days to see if there is anything more identifiable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit**

Thanks for the picture, by any chance are their any identifying text left on the packages or the boards? Just a shot in the dark, but I would say that board was from the aprox: 1972 to 1985. But it depends on so many other factors. And it also my not be original to the organ it'self.

---

**Original Answer**

> I'm trying to date a circuit from an organ.

It would be the easiest to just look up the organ...

> Date of introduction of TO-92 transistors. Approximately when did
>   these transistors first appear?

The [TO-92](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TO-92) spec was introduced in the 1960's (I believe but can't find a source,) and became a standard by [JEDEC Solid State Technology Association](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JEDEC) years later.

FYI, none of this information will help you date the organ's board!

**It depends on the actual model of the transistor and a few other factors. Semiconductor material (date first used):**

- the metalloids germanium (1947) and silicon (1954)
- in amorphous, polycrystalline and monocrystalline form
- the compounds gallium arsenide (1966)
- silicon carbide (1997)
- the alloy silicon-germanium (1989)
- the allotrope of carbon graphene (research ongoing since 2004)

Comment: That is surprisingly late - I was told the organ was a late 50s model. I don't have the organ to hand so can't investigate any further than a photo I have. I will add the photo to my question.

Comment: @c.cam108 1980 was a typo, I meant 1960's. But like I said, *can't find a source.* I listed the dates of the technology, so maybe that would help. Also I see you just added a picture too. I'll email my father, he would know. Or I can dust off one of my old Motorola parts books...

Comment: Yes 1960s was what my dad assumed when I asked him. Definitely not 1950s though.

Comment: @c.cam108 see my update. (If I was betting on it, it would I would probably go in around ~1974. But just a stab in the dark!) I'm out door now, but I can link a few blogs that you could ask on. They love this type of stuff...

Comment: The resistors look like the ones in my Kosmos set: http://www.radiomuseum.org/r/kosmos_radio_elektronik_1.html

Answer (score 1):

Look for date codes on (unlikely) the transistors; (likely) any TO3 transistors in the power supply; definitely ICs if there are any; and (sometimes) large electrolytic capacitors, again in the PSU. Also that screened can (inductor?).

Earlier than 1970 I think the TO18 can would be more common (there's 1 in your picture) and much later, ICs would start appearing (along with 5% resistors rather than 10%) so I doubt it's as late as 1980.